# Applying for student visa (Poland) from a third country (US)

Tags: visa, documentation

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: Third country is USA.

My citizenship is from El Salvador

My destination country is Poland

Hello, I am currently an asylum seeker in the US, my court date regarding the approval of it would be in a month. I saw my lawyer last week and he said in case of denial, I could ask for a voluntary departure which would give me 90 days to prepare everything. I don't want to be an illegal immigrant here in the US as it's been already few years and I want to try to achieve something in my life. I’m grateful for what US gave me however I feel like it's time to move further as I feel trapped and unmotivated. My boyfriend lives in Europe (Poland), and he suggested that I could study there. I've always wanted to go to college but unfortunately it's not possible to do it here in the US, therefore it would be a dream coming true.

Most of the requirements, I already meet but one which is student visa.

To apply for one in the polish embassy here in the US, I need to be a Green card holder or citizen, which I am not.

So my question is, is there a way for me to apply for a visa in a third country without me going to my home country?

Comment: You generally need to be accepted as a student at some university in Poland before you can apply for a Polish student visa.

Answer (score 1):

On the website for the consulate of Poland in Los Angeles you'll find:

> 3. PROOF OF LEGAL RESIDENCE in the USA and valid re-entry document:
>
> -original of Permanent Residence Card (Green Card) or notarized copy,
>
> -or valid US resident visa type A, E, F (with endorsed I-20), G, H, I, J plus J1 documents, L, O, R;
>
> Tourists and visitors with US visa type B1/B2 and J1 Summer Work
>   Travel visas must apply in their country of residence.
>
> The US residence permit or visa should be valid at least three months
>   beyond the intended departure from the territory of Poland or other
>   Member States (Schengen).

Therefore, they don't limit issuance of visas to USC and LPR. However, your case is a bit different because you don't have immigration documents that would go "beyond the intended departure from Poland".

I would contact them directly and see what they can do for you. Each consulate/country has different rules regarding visa issuance for third-country nationals.